# ImportError when using virtualenv in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

My Question is pretty Simple.

Whenever I use virtualenv environment in my Django project it gives the following error when executed this command

> *python manage.py runserver*
>
> File "manage.py", line 8, in

```
 from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

But when i use root and give the same command it seems to work perfectly. Why does this Happen? I am in the virtualenv so it means i am the root person by default.How can i fix this error?

I had seen many forums but couldn't find related to mine.

Comment: create a new virtualenv using `virtualenv venv --system-site-packages`

Comment: Should i do that do that inside already my working directory or deactivate it first?

Comment: does pip list show django installed?

Comment: I don't get you @utkbansal . Where should i check? inside pip folder

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you have installed django in the system-wide Python interpreter; possibly by doing something like `sudo pip install django`.

Once you create a virtual environment and activate it - it contains no packages. The concept of a virtual environment is that it allows you to install Python packages without affecting the global Python installation.

So once you activate a virtual environment, you have to install packages in that virtual environment; so you should `pip install django` (note: without sudo) once you activate the virtual environment; like this:

```
$ virtualenv sample_env
...
$ source sample_env/bin/activate
(sample_env) $ pip install django
```

A virtual environment is a virtual environment for *Python*; it does not control what the user is that is logged into the system.

Finally, as a general rule - you should not be using root for development purposes as doing so can easily compromise your system.

Comment: thanks Burhan , yes i had done that with sudo. But i was forced to do that because without sudo gives me an error like >/home/usman/Django: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: It seems you have corrupted the file permissions on your system - probably from misuse of `sudo`.

Comment: Hmm. Any idea how should i fix? And references

Answer (score 2):

Yup i have same error while running Django. I also have enabled virtual environment. But I was still getting error.

> Solution to this problem is using this command to install any python package
>   `python -m pip install django`

This will definitely solve your problem. As it solved mine.

Comment: worked for me also, I could run my project in my server but not on my pc and this did it